# Removing or customizing drop-down sorting menu for woocommerce for specific product-category

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to either remove the product sorting or customize the sorting options for one specific product-category while not effecting the sorting for all other pages/categories on my site.

I found [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/93906/style-product-detail-page-with-custom-css-in-woocommerce); I have added the code to the functions.php, but I am not sure what to do next.

I would like to either remove the "*Sort by Price*" and have only "*Sort by A-Z*" and "*Sort by Z-A*" or remove the sorting altogether.

Let's say product category's name is "**BrandABC**". So on my site the url would appear as follows:
http://www.mywebsite.com/product-category/brandABC/

I found out that page has the following while editing the product-category:

```
taxonomy=product_cat&tag_ID=13&post_type=product......
```

I've tried putting this in the custom CSS of my theme:

```
.product_cat .id-13 .woocommerce-ordering {
    display: none;
}
```

also tried:

```
.product_cat&tag_ID=13 .woocommerce-ordering {
    display: none;
}
```

Neither worked. How would I identify and target just the BrandABC page?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The .term-13 did nothing but the .term-brandabc worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Product Category Archive page WooCommerce adds dynamic class in
>   `body` tag like `term-your-cat-slug` and `term-your-term-ID`.

For Example if your product category name is: *Example Category* and it slug is *example-category* and term ID is *10*; then WooCommerce will add following class in `body` tag

```
term-example-category term-10
```

So you can add any of the following CSS code to your active theme style.css or child theme style.css

```
.term-brandabc .woocommerce-ordering{
    display: none;
}
```

Alternative CSS (Recommended):

```
.term-13 .woocommerce-ordering{
    display: none;
}
```

Hope this helps!